# Pass reference-type by reference to indicate it will be modified

Tags: c#, ref

I found some code in our app that passes a `List<T>` by reference to indicate it is modified:

```
void DoSomething(ref List<MyType> theList)
{
    theList.Add(new MyType());
}
```

I think it is clear that the ref-keyword is obsolete in this case, as we could also add new elements to the list without the keyword. However it indicates that we modify the lists or at least its elements. I find this is particulary useful if you have many parameters and want to see which of them are modified and which are just passed as values to do the job.

The question if this is okay is surely opinion-based and would be invalid for SO, I rather ask if there´s another approach to achieve this or if I even should care about it.

EDIT: To clarify my question a bit. This question is **not** on if a list is modified, this was just an example. Alternatively I´d also use any other reference-type, not just a `List<T>`.

Comment: Are you looking for an equivalent to C++ `const` for parameters?

Comment: @BernhardHiller I doubt so, I want to indicate a parameter is *modified* in my method, not the opposite.

Comment: In C# there is no equivalent for C++ const modifiers. This effect achieves through interface implementations and restrictions inside wrappers.

Comment: Using keywords that have an *actual function* as vague documentation (for something that is even unrelated to the actual keyword) seems outright crazy to me - I'd probably advise that if you need to denote in your parameter list which parameters are "changed" that you just need to do some heavy refactoring to make your code easier to follow. Start by taking out `ref` keywords that you don't need.

Comment: The correct way to do this is use `IReadOnlyList<T>` (or `ImmutableList<T>`) parameters to indicate when a list will *not* be modified, and assume that the contents of any `List<T>` parameters WILL be modified. Of course, this doesn't work well with legacy code, but it's still the correct approach.

Comment: @MatthewWatson See my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However it indicates that we're changing the list.

No, it does not. It indicates the reference can be changed. Using a `ref` keyword as 'identifier' something can change is bad in my opinion since it opens doors you might not want.

I would advice to look into aspect-oriented programming, were you can assign attributes to method parameters. From the new Roslyn compiler with its code analysis services you could even check if the code violates the principal given.

Comment: Relying on attributes could be an option, however I suppose as our team doesn´t use this compiler an alternative approach is to just rely on the API-doc of the method.

Comment: That is possible indeed. Roslyn is used by VS 2015, so it is well possible you are already using it.

Comment: We´re actually using VS2010 :)

Comment: i didnt get why it may be bad to give ref word? also visual studio doesnt show explicitly which given objects are reference or not. ref word makes it explicit

Answer (score 0):

Patrick lead me to an alternative way that doesn't rely on attributes so we can use it in legacy-code on machines with an older compiler. We can of course write the API-doc appropriately to indicate that the method modifies the passed parameter:

```
/// <summary/>
/// <param name="theList">list to be modified</param>
void DoSomething(List<MyType> theList)
```

I guess this is better as it doesn't rely on a wrong usage of the keyword. However it assumes clients of our API read the docs carefully.

Answer (score -2):

It is much easier and broad to read **interface** than see ref and consider it changable collection.

For example, if you want it to be constant:

```
public DoSomething<T>(IReadOnlyCollection<T> collection)
{
     //....
}
```

Non-constant:

```
public DoSomething<T>(List<T> collection)
{
     //....
}
```

In case of value type it is indeed as you clarify in your question:

Constant:

```
public DoSomething(int value)
{
     //....
}
```

Non-constant:

```
public DoSomething(ref int value)
{
     //....
}
```

Or, if you have type without access to code, for example, Stream:

```
public class StreamWrapper
{
    private Stream _instance;

    //now you can specify read or edit methods here and use this class in invokation.
}
```

Comment: The list is just one example of course. There are multiple types that don't support that interface. For `List<T>` it is a good option though.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks to clearify this was just an example. There could of course be any arbitrary type passed to the method.

Comment: Why is everyone downvoting without arguing?

Comment: The question was not on what the ref-keyword does usually, but if there is another (better) approach to indicate a parameter is *modified* (**not re-assigned**).

Comment: And where I actually reasign referenced type in my examples? I mention reasigning only when we are talking about value types cause it is how they work.

Comment: I can´t see anything in your code that indicates a modification of the param. Again: I´m not just interest in lists, but on any arbitrary reference-type.

Comment: I thought it pretty obvious, but I added example.