# How am i able to pass private object to another class by reference?

Tags: c#, .net, private-members, .net-4.6.2

I just noticed that i am able to pass private object to another class by a reference

I would guess this should not be possible but it works fine

Here an example

```
private static StreamWriter swYandexErrors; // in classA

 csLogger.logAnyError(ref swYandexErrors, $"msg", E); // in classA

// in class csLogger
    public static void logAnyError(ref StreamWriter swError, 
string srError, Exception E = null)
    {
        lock (swError)
        {
            swError.WriteLine("");
            swError.Flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you expect this to not be possible? `private` hides a value from the classes outside the class it is declared in. You can still pass it to functions within that class.

Comment: @DarthJam so passing into other classes are not a problem. i see

Comment: What is the problem? You still call it inside your classA. If you could pass it from outside of classA: an instance of ClassA or another class, it is problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`private` means just private for that **variable**, not for the **actual instance** which is *referenced by that variable*. So the *reference* `swYandexErrors` which is `private` in your class is of course not visible to the other one. However as you´re passing the *instance* **by reference** you can of course access the *instance* within your first class.

To be more clear the following does **not** work in class `csLogger` and causes a compiler-error as you can´t access `swYandexErrors` within `csLogger`:

```
public static void DoSomething()
{
    ClassA.swYandexErrors.Read();
}
```

As an aside: you don´t even need the `ref`-keyword in your method, as you don´t *re-assign* the passed `StreamWriter`. All you´re doing is to call members on the passed instance.

Comment: ty for the answer. yes i know i dont need ref word since it is reference type but putting ref makes it explicitly more clear when reading :)

Comment: Don´t do this to identify you´re calling or changing the members of your instance. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802039/pass-reference-type-by-reference-to-indicate-it-will-be-modified

Comment: but visual studio does not explicitly shows which objects are reference type or not. so i just want to be sure also. also i didnt get why it may be bad to give ref word?

Comment: It seems you misunderstand what `ref` means. Anyway I can´t see any reason to know if a variable is a reference- or a value-type. In doubt you´ll get a compiler-error very soon if you use the whrong one.

Comment: Ok after playing a bit with few examples i understood. ref value is only needed when the object is re-composed by new assigment